Karate 1.5.0 - troubles with Page Switch
Using Karate 1.5.0 (Java 22) I have troubles with PageSwitch.
In previous Karate versions It works fine (1.2.0, Java 11), but now I am experimenting with 1.5.0. and It does not work now:
I tried:

switchPage('Page One') (it worked under 1.2.0, not under 1.5.0)
switchPage(1), switchPage(2)...

But not working for me under 1.5.0
Any advise please?

well maybe it is a bug. no one else has reported this, so perhaps you can file an issue with a clear way to replicate: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue
